# Dynamically Adjusting an element with javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to dynamically adjust the position of a YouTube video element using javascript based on the browser dimensions. I am not looking for a purely CSS Solution, I know that I can do that with padding, I am looking for a javascript solution which alters CSS of the div.
In this instance my DIV is "wrappervideo"

```
<script>
var viewWidth = window.innerWidth;
var viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
var narrowPadding = (((viewWidth/1.7777)-(viewHeight/1.5))/2);
var tallHeight = (viewHeight/1.5);
var tallWidth = (viewHeight/1.5)*1.7777;
var tallPadding = ((viewWidth)-(viewHeight/1.5)1.7777)/2;

function findAspectRatio() {
     if ( viewWidth/(viewHeight/1.5) >= 1.777) {
      setTimeout(narrow,0)}
     if ( viewWidth/(viewHeight/1.5) <= 1.777) {
      setTimeout(tall,0)}
     if ( viewWidth/(viewHeight/1.5) == 1.777) {
      setTimeout(equal,0)}
      }

function equal() {
    wrappervideo.style.top = '0px';
    wrappervideo.style.width = '100%'; }
function narrow() {
    wrappervideo.style.top = narrowPadding;
    wrappervideo.style.width = '100%'; }
function tall() { 
    wrappervideo.style.right = tallPadding;
    wrappervideo.style.width = tallWidth; }

 </script>
```

Edited - This is what I have currently. Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: Might not be what's breaking it, but `wrappervideo.style.topp == narrowPadding;` should only be one _p_

Comment: What is `done`, where is it used, and where is it created?

Comment: For starters, the initial line, `var viewWidth = vw`, assign a variable, `vw`, that is not defined, none of the script will work

Comment: Thanks guys! I fixed spelling and variable mistakes and removed the legacy 'done'

Comment: I think you're missing semicolons after value assignation in first lines of your code. Check your code with a debugger like Chrome DevTools, it will tell you where your code is breaking.

Comment: @Syncro Semicolons is not mandatory(well in some cases), though recommended

Comment: @LGSon I didn't know that. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Patrick You can use `window.innerHeight`/`window.innerWidth` to get the viewport size

Comment: @LGSon - thank you. I've updated the code!